# Что такое именованный тип данных?

Tags: c#, терминология, типы-данных

В экзаменационном билете есть вопрос : Что такое именованный тип данных. Опишите как он используется." Я что-то не пойму,это имеются ввиду строки?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Тип, явно объявленный с именем. Например, любой класс или структура, которые вы объявляете, является именованным типом.

Пример именованного типа:

```
public struct CoOrds
{
    public int x, y;

    public CoOrds(int p1, int p2)
    {
        x = p1;
        y = p2;
    }
}
```

Существуют также анонимные типы, объявленные без имени, и компилятор присваивает имя этому типу, недоступное разработчику.

Пример анонимного типа:

```
var v = new { 
    Amount = 108, 
    Message = "Hello" 
};
```

Вы можете больше узнать о различных [типах в C#.](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/index)

Comment: *именованный*, наверное, а не именуемый - такой первый раз слышу

Comment: Вы правы, исправил ответ.

Comment: И неплохо бы дополнить ответ парой примеров, когда компилятор не присваивает имя и какие символы при этом использует, чтобы гарантировать недоступность переменных по имени.

Comment: Хорошо было бы показать разницу в коде, если автор вопроса не знает про именованные типы, то такое понятие как анонимные типы ситуацию не сильно проясняет.